# Dask not installing graphviz dependency

Tags: python, anaconda, graphviz, conda, dask

I'm getting an error when I try to import `dask.dot` that it can't find the graphviz install. However, both graphviz and pygraphviz are installed.

```
balter@exalab3:~$ conda install dask
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/.../miniconda3:
#
dask                      0.13.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
balter@exalab3:~$ python
Python 3.5.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 23 2017, 19:01:48)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dask.dot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 63, in import_required
    return import_module(mod_name)
  File "/home/.../miniconda3/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'graphviz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.../miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dot.py", line 11, in <module>
    graphviz = import_required("graphviz", "Drawing dask graphs requires the "
  File "/home/.../miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 65, in import_required
    raise RuntimeError(error_msg)
RuntimeError: Drawing dask graphs requires the `graphviz` python library and the `graphviz` system library to be installed.
>>>
balter@exalab3:~$ conda install graphviz
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/.../miniconda3:
#
graphviz                  2.38.0                        4    bioconda
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The github issue referenced in MRocklin's answer got updated. 
I fixed the problem with the following lines:

`conda install -c conda-forge graphviz`

`conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz`

This comment explains this https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/485#issuecomment-279296254

conda list output:

bleach                    1.5.0                    py35_0
bokeh                     0.12.5                   py35_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
chest                     0.2.3                    py35_0
click                     6.7                      py35_0
cloudpickle               0.2.2                    py35_0
colorama                  0.3.9                    py35_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0
cython                    0.25.2                   py35_1    conda-forge
dask                      0.14.1                   py35_0
decorator                 4.0.11                   py35_0
distributed               1.16.1                   py35_0
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py35_1
fastparquet               0.0.5                    py35_1    conda-forge
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_2  [vc14]
graphviz                  2.38.0                        4    conda-forge
h5py                      2.7.0               np112py35_0
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                 vc14_4  [vc14]
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py35_1
html5lib                  0.999                    py35_0
icu                       57.1                     vc14_0  [vc14]
ipykernel                 4.6.1                    py35_0
ipython                   6.0.0                    py35_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py35_0
ipywidgets                6.0.0                    py35_0
jinja2                    2.9.6                    py35_0
jpeg                      9b                       vc14_0  [vc14]
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py35_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3
jupyter_client            5.0.1                    py35_0
jupyter_console           5.1.0                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py35_0
libpng                    1.6.27                   vc14_0  [vc14]
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
llvmlite                  0.17.0                   py35_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py35_1
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2
matplotlib                2.0.0               np112py35_0
mistune                   0.7.4                    py35_0
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0
msgpack-python            0.4.8                    py35_0
nbconvert                 5.1.1                    py35_0
nbformat                  4.3.0                    py35_0
notebook                  5.0.0                    py35_0
numba                     0.32.0              np112py35_0
numexpr                   2.6.2               np112py35_0
numpy                     1.12.1                   py35_0
olefile                   0.44                     py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2k                   vc14_0  [vc14]
pandas                    0.19.2              np112py35_1
pandocfilters             1.4.1                    py35_0
partd                     0.3.7                    py35_0
path.py                   10.3.1                   py35_0
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py35_0
pillow                    4.1.0                    py35_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1
ply                       3.9                      py35_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            1.0.14                   py35_0
psutil                    5.2.2                    py35_0
py                        1.4.33                   py35_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.2.0                    py35_0
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py35_0
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_2
pytables                  3.2.2               np112py35_4
pytest                    3.0.7                    py35_0    conda-forge
python                    3.5.3                         0
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py35_0
python-graphviz           0.6                      py35_1    conda-forge
pytz                      2017.2                   py35_0
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_0
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py35_0
qt                        5.6.2                    vc14_3  [vc14]
qtconsole                 4.3.0                    py35_0
requests                  2.13.0                   py35_0
scipy                     0.19.0              np112py35_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py35_1
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_1
sip                       4.18                     py35_0
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
sortedcollections         0.5.3                    py35_0
sortedcontainers          1.5.7                    py35_0
tblib                     1.3.2                    py35_0
testpath                  0.3                      py35_0
thriftpy                  0.3.9                    py35_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]
toolz                     0.8.2                    py35_0
tornado                   4.4.2                    py35_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py35_0
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py35_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
widgetsnbextension        2.0.0                    py35_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py35_0
zict                      0.1.1                    py35_0
zlib                      1.2.8                    vc14_3  [vc14]

Answer (score 2):

[Dask documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/graphviz.html) has been updated for the graphviz installation issue:

> You must install both the graphviz system library (with tools like
> apt-get, yum, or brew) and the graphviz Python library. If you use
> Conda then you need to install python-graphviz, which will bring along
> the graphviz system library as a dependency.

As mentioned following will install both the python and system graphviz library:

> conda install -c anaconda python-graphviz

However, at least once I had to explicitly install graphviz library (In addition to installing through conda using the command above):

> sudo apt install graphviz

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding the conda `graphviz` package.  See discussion here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/485

Instead install graphviz using your system installer (brew, apt-get, or download a Windows installer) and pip install the graphviz package after installing the system library.

Comment: We are using conda as our default package manager. And, dask is a product of Anaconda. So, if Anaconda's package manager is not properly installing their product, then there is something going on that is worth looking into.

Comment: Oh, and more importantly, I'm working on a large cluster I don't manage. But I am maintaining the conda packages. Everything is being handled by `conda install`.

Comment: Then you are out of luck.  You need to install a working graphviz to use `dask.dot` or `dask.visualize`